# RallyDev: ConversationPost- How to query for Discussions in RallyDev Story

Tags: rally, hierarchical

I am using the following RallyApi service to communicate with RallyDev:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.40/RallyService

I have the following method:

```
    public HierarchicalRequirement GetFeedbackById(string usid)
    {
        var query = string.Format("(FormattedID = \"{0}\")", usid);
        const string orderByString = "CreationDate desc";
        var rallyService = GetRallyService();
        var rtnval = rallyService.query(Workspace, Projs["XXX"], true, true,"HierarchicalRequirement", query,
                           orderByString, true, 1, 20).Results[0] as HierarchicalRequirement;
        return rtnval;
    }
```

Although I am successfully retrieving the "HierarchicalRquirement" object using the "FormattedID", I am not able to load the associated "ConversationPost" objects for this story, Since all the nested complex objects of the "HierarchicalRquirement" contains the "ref" and "reffield" property and nothing else.

Could you please let me know if there is a way to actively load all the associated  discussions when we query for the story or if there is a query as follows:

```
   rallyService.query(Workspace, Projs["XXX"], true, true, "ConversationPost", query, orderByString, true, 1, 20)
```

Using the above can I search for discussions(ConversationPost) using FormattedID?

Thanks for your help.

Regards,
Varun

Comment: Guess I figured out how to load the discussions for a given HierarchicalRequirement, Added the below line to the method(GetFeedbackById) mentioned above:

     rtnval.Discussion.Select(discussion => rallyService.read(discussion) as ConversationPost)

Please let me know if there is a better way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right on target with your use of rallyService.read(). With SOAP, even with fetchFullObjects=true, any Artifact attributes that are themselves Rally objects, are hydrated with refs to those object.

Especially if you're just getting started with building your integration, I'd highly recommend using REST:

http://developer.help.rallydev.com/rest-apis

instead of SOAP.

REST is more robust, more performant, and, the soon-to-be-released Webservices API 1.41, will be the final API release to have SOAP support. Webservices 2.x will be REST-only, so using REST will be essential to anyone wanting new Webservices features moving forward.